# A very strange behavior of service stack

Tags: wcf-rest, servicestack

I am currently working on azure platform to get performance data in my application.
My client needs to attach my console application which fetches data in there webrole startup task and it works for them in my application

I had used WCF in my project, now I want to change it and use Service stack instead to get better performance.

I am now facing issue in live.

In local development environment, all the console application and service stack works fine and insert data in DB.

When I test it in live with all the necessary settings (of course my old exe is still working which use WCF service reference till) and upload test application and in that set start up task to my console application, it is not working.

Although, when I open the RDP of test application hosted on azure, I can see that EXE is running (in task manager),

I also try to access the REST Service stack in RDP, it is also works and I can fire GET request in that.

All the messages, I have written in my application (Console) I can see when start the EXE manually in RDP.

But it doesn't insert the data in my DB. (it is working in my local)

The very strange thing I found, when my application RUN I see a message in console, which is not written by me.

Can anyone tell me for what this message says?

[image]

I have done some research and find out I need to supply service stack (.dlls) with my exe separately to work this properly.
The question is that, I think it should automatically reference with my console application EXE which I supply to my client, because in project I already give reference to services stack dlls.
Is anyone having idea, why it is needed to supply separately?.